# Header-Footer using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

In a report I must write, there has to be a specific header and footer on each series of even and odd pages.
These headers and footers include pictures.

I have never made a header nor a footer in LaTeX. Could someone explain me how to make these, include pictures and customize them for even and odd page numbers using the fancyhdr package please?

Comment: This is literally described in the [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/fancyhdr). Have you read the documentation? Have you tried anything?

Comment: please add the sketch of the desired output